# YouTube offline videos captions not seen on playback

Tags: youtube, video, offline, subtitles

I have saved a YouTube video of 1.5 hrs after verifying that it has captions(Offline videos).

However when I play the offline video with the captions on, it still doesn't show any captions.

Please help to get the captions. Hope the offline saved video doesn't need to go waste. Please suggest any alternatives.

Comment: How did you save the video? Presumably you have the captions file?

Comment: i do not have the captions file. they were mostly autogenerated captions. does .srt work on mobiles? Im not sure if ill get .srt file as its a korean show and i dont know if they put on torrents.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 11 times. I’m voting to close this question because YouTube offline is a mobile app feature, not available for the web application. Questions about the YouTube mobile app might be asked in [android.se] or [apple.se].

Answer (score 0):

I tried going to my YouTube settings, then to captions and changed the captions style. After that I opened the video I downloaded offline and it worked: it showed the subtitles again. Maybe that trick would work for you too next time you have that problem again.